# Uploading large amounts of data in bulk to a Cloud SQL instance via Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a Python application that uses a Cloud SQL instance to store data. The application usually runs on a Google Compute Engine but is run locally during development and testing. At some point I need to update two separate tables with a number of rows in the order of one hundred thousands rows each. Rows will already exist in most cases and only require an `UPDATE` for a single column 'val' but may also require an INSERT statement in some cases. Using an `INSERT` statement with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with the SQLAlchemy connection works but took almost half an hour (for around half a million rows) when the actual calculation only took 5 minutes in my test case.

So now I'm wondering if there's a faster way to make those changes in bulk. The Cloud SQL database is running MySQL 5.7. I tried using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement with a csv file but lack the required permissions and haven't been able to figure out how (if at all) this is possible with Cloud SQL. Uploading the csv to a bucket and then using `LOAD DATA INFILE` (i.e. without the `LOCAL`) also fails due to a lack of permissions.
How can I grant the required permissions to the Cloud SQL user logged in to the database or - alternatively - is there another way of updating/inserting those rows in bulk?

Edit:
The way I got it to work, albeit slowly, is by running the following SQL statement via SQLAlchemy session.execute for each single row:

```
INSERT INTO my_database.my_table (position_id, type, date, val)
VALUES (<position_id>, "<type>", "<date>", <val>)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val=<val>
```

This statement is run for each row through a for loop and after the loop terminates, a session.commit() persists the changes to the database.
In my test this took about 18 minutes to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` a total of 417374 rows.

As an alternative I suppose I could simply try to run a simple `UPDATE` statement and only if the rowcount is 0 `INSERT` it (or vice versa). This took about 20 minutes for 5 `INSERTS` and 417369 `UPDATES`.

Keeping in mind that most rows, identified by `position_id`, `type` and `date`, a) will already exist and b) may already have the desired value  (i.e. don't even have to be updated), as a third option I could also try getting the value, comparing it to the val to be written and only writing it if it either doesn't exist or differs. This could improve performance if reading access is significantly faster than writing.

I'll try and benchmark all of the above and post my results here once I have them. What I can already say is that the time it takes to run the actual for loop without the SQL part is negligible and can be disregarded for the purpose of improving performance for the whole process.

Comment: You haven't shown your code, so there might be optimizations to be made in the way you're committing the changes. Impossible to say. You might like to review my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: As for how to gain the permissions, you should talk to your cloud vendor support for that. But in my experience, cloud vendors like Google and Amazon don't grant that permission. You can search past questions on Stack Overflow or dba.stackexchange.com to confirm.

Comment: I added the exact SQL statement to my original question. Let me know if you need more information.